# Google Sheets - Formula to Concatenate Text in Range of Cells based on Numeric Value in Corresponding Range of Cells

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I have this setup in Google Sheets:

[image: Google Sheet set up]

Row 1 is a list of ingredients. Rows 2-6 are specific plans that contain combinations of ingredients A-F - if there is a 1 in the column, it contains the ingredient in the column.

In column H, I want to concatenate the letters in row 1 if there is a 1 underneath it.
So the formula I'm looking for in Col H should spit out the following:

1. Cell H2 --> A + B
2. Cell H3 --> A + C
3. Cell H4 --> A + B + D
4. Cell H5 --> A + C + D
5. Cell H6 --> A

I've tried the TEXTJOIN formula you see in the formula bar but it's not working. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I just figured it out. I had to change my formula above to:

```
=textjoin(" + ", TRUE, arrayformula(IF($B7:$G7=1, $B$1:$G$1,"")))
```

Comment: You can also use: `=textjoin(" + ", TRUE, Filter($B$1:$G$1,$B7:$G7=1))`

Comment: oh wow, I never knew about the Filter function in Sheets - much more intuitive. Love it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anthony,

If I got it correctly what you want to combine, another option to do that is to use **CONCATENATE + IF**.

I needed to combine 5 columns but make a note while a cell contains particular data (e.g., when X is in the cell, not to combine columns but write a comment). And the combination of CONCATENATE + IF worked.

I found this solution [here](https://blog.coupler.io/google-sheets-concatenate-function).

Hope it'll be somehow helpful :)